# How do I convert this hash to an array of hashes?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have this hash below called `disciplines`:

```
disciplines = {"Architecture"=>"architecture", "Auditing"=>"auditing", "Consulting"=>"consulting", "Delivery"=>"delivery", "Development"=>"development", "Engineering"=>"engineering", "Environment / IT"=>"environment", "Graphic Design"=>"graphic_design", "Management"=>"management", "Requirements"=>"requirements", "Research"=>"research", "Support"=>"support", "System Design"=>"system_design", "Test & Eval"=>"test_and_evaluation", "Writing"=>"writing"}
```

And I want to convert it into an array of hashes that looks like this:

```
[{"name"=>"Architecture", "value"=>"architecture"}, {"name"=>"Auditing", "value"=>"auditing"}, {"name"=>"Consulting", "value"=>"consulting"}, {"name"=>"Delivery", "value"=>"delivery"}, {"name"=>"Development", "value"=>"development"}, {"name"=>"Engineering", "value"=>"engineering"}, {"name"=>"Environment / IT", "value"=>"environment"}, {"name"=>"Graphic Design", "value"=>"graphic_design"}, {"name"=>"Management", "value"=>"management"}, {"name"=>"Requirements", "value"=>"requirements"}, {"name"=>"Research", "value"=>"research"}, {"name"=>"Support", "value"=>"support"}, {"name"=>"System Design", "value"=>"system_design"}, {"name"=>"Test & Eval", "value"=>"test_and_evaluation"}, {"name"=>"Writing", "value"=>"writing"}]
```

So I just want to take each key-value pair in the first hash and map it to a new hash where the key is now a value for `name` and the value is now a value for `value` and put them all in an array of hashes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
disciplines.map{ |k, v| { 'name' => k, 'value' => v } }
```

to achieve that.

Here's a demo: http://ideone.com/DBU3Ck

Answer (score 1):

You can also do in this way:

```
array_of_hashes = disciplines.keys.inject([]) do |arr_of_hsh, item|
      arr_of_hsh << ({name: item.downcase,value: item.capitalize})
    end
```

Output will be look like this:

```
# array_of_hashes => [{:name=>"architecture", :value=>"Architecture"}, {:name=>"auditing", :value=>"Auditing"}, {:name=>"consulting", :value=>"Consulting"}, {:name=>"delivery", :value=>"Delivery"}, {:name=>"development", :value=>"Development"}, {:name=>"engineering", :value=>"Engineering"}, {:name=>"environment / it", :value=>"Environment / it"}, {:name=>"graphic design", :value=>"Graphic design"}, {:name=>"management", :value=>"Management"}, {:name=>"requirements", :value=>"Requirements"}, {:name=>"research", :value=>"Research"}, {:name=>"support", :value=>"Support"}, {:name=>"system design", :value=>"System design"}, {:name=>"test & eval", :value=>"Test & eval"}, {:name=>"writing", :value=>"Writing"}]
```